# FB-api: The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I try to post on my wall using facebook api, and offline access tokens. 
And every time I has one mistake:

> Uncaught OAuthException: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the
>   application to perform this action

Here is my code:

```
require 'api/facebook.php';

    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => "app_id",
        'secret' => "app_sec",
        "cookie" => true,
        'fileUpload' => true
    ));

    $facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);  

    $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
    $user_id = $facebook->getUser();

$result = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET user_id_facebook='".$user_id."' WHERE id='".$myrow2['id']."'",$db);
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET access_token_facebook='".$access_token."' WHERE id='".$myrow2['id']."'",$db);

    if($user_id == 0 || $user_id == "")
    {
        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        'redirect_uri'         => "http://apps.facebook.com/rapid-apps/",
        'scope'      => "email,publish_stream,user_hometown,user_location,user_photos,friends_photos,
                    user_photo_video_tags,friends_photo_video_tags,user_videos,video_upload,friends_videos,offline_access"));

        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$login_url';</script>";
        exit();
    }

    $post =  array(
    'access_token' => $access_token,
    'message' => 'This message is posted with access token - '
);

$res = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', $post);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as of may 2nd the offline_access permission will be deprecated and should not be used anymore

in the meantime you have an option to disable this deprecation through the developers site for your application ( https://developers.facebook.com/apps/330955886953999 )...

for further information about the removal see:
http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the permissions in your initial app authorization request sent to the user. By default you only gain read-only access to their basic information.

See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/